# scrapy - not able to upload data to s3

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to **scrape** the data from one website which is working fine but i am not able to upload the **scraped** data onto amazon s3

Looking at the scrapy documentation this is what I have in my `settings.py`

```
FEED_URI = 's3://bucket/folder/data-%(time)s.csv'
FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'key-goes-here'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'secret-key-goes-here'

FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS = None
FEED_STORAGES = {}

FEED_STORAGES_BASE = {
    '': 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FileFeedStorage',
    'file': 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FileFeedStorage',
    'stdout': 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.StdoutFeedStorage',
    's3': 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.S3FeedStorage',
    'ftp': 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FTPFeedStorage',
}
FEED_EXPORTERS = {}
FEED_EXPORTERS_BASE = {
    'json': 'scrapy.exporters.JsonItemExporter',
    'jsonlines': 'scrapy.exporters.JsonLinesItemExporter',
    'jl': 'scrapy.exporters.JsonLinesItemExporter',
    'csv': 'scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter',
    'xml': 'scrapy.exporters.XmlItemExporter',
    'marshal': 'scrapy.exporters.MarshalItemExporter',
    'pickle': 'scrapy.exporters.PickleItemExporter',
}

ITEM_PIPELINE = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.files.S3FilesStore': 1
}
```

here is my environment details in case of this is helpful

```
Scrapy       : 1.5.0
lxml         : 4.1.1.0
libxml2      : 2.9.7
cssselect    : 1.0.3
parsel       : 1.4.0
w3lib        : 1.19.0
Twisted      : 18.4.0
Python       : 3.6.4 (default, Mar 10 2018, 19:20:23) - [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)]
pyOpenSSL    : 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018)
cryptography : 2.2.2
Platform     : Darwin-17.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
```

When I run the **scraper** it runs fine, there are no crashes however I did notice in the log following line, I am not sure why this is and how to enable it.

> [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] ERROR: Disabled feed storage scheme: s3

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown from the _storage_support function present in

> scrapy/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py

```
def _storage_supported(self, uri):
    scheme = urlparse(uri).scheme
    if scheme in self.storages:
        try:
            self._get_storage(uri)
            return True
        except NotConfigured:
            logger.error("Disabled feed storage scheme: %(scheme)s",
                         {'scheme': scheme})
    else:
        logger.error("Unknown feed storage scheme: %(scheme)s",
                     {'scheme': scheme})
```

There seems to be some problem with your URI Parameter.

Refer this document

> https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#csvitemexporter

Comment: Locally everything seems to be working fine, I am able to get the feed exported in a csv, its only when i want it to upload the export on aws the problem occurs.